# Using \maketitle twice in the same article

Tags: article, titles

I need to write a single, short PDF file that contains two distinct parts.  I don't want to mess with PDF joins and hacks, as I need both parts to share page numbers, citations, etc.  However, I want to use an article-like style for the sections and so on - A report style is an overkill.  Is there a way to run `\maketitle` twice on the same document?  Without additional hacks it yields no result (since that it is redefined to `\relax` after the first expand).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe the [titling](http://ctan.org/pkg/titling) package does what you want.

From documentation:

> The package inhibits the normal
>   automatic cancellation of titling
>   commands after `\maketitle`. This means
>   that you can have multiple instances
>   of the same, or perhaps different,
>   titles in one document. Hooks are
>   provided so that additional titling
>   elements can be defined and printed by
>   `\maketitle`.

If you want to shrink the amount of room your title takes up (apparently `titling` increases it slightly) you can add `\setlength{\droptitle}{-1in}`. This decreases the vertical space above your title by an inch. You can set it to whatever you like.

You can also redefine `\pretitle` `\posttitle` and similar commands to include less vertical space between elements of the title. Do so with care, you don't want to cramp your title too much. See the [documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titling/titling.pdf) for examples.

Comment: in my case it changed the style ... not using it.