# Two 'maketitle's in article

Tags: titles

I'm writing a report with two parts using the `article` class.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}   
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\title{\huge Title1 \\}
\author{\normalfont                 \normalsize
    Author\\                        \normalsize
    Supervisors: Prof. X}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\part{Heisenberg Picture}

\maketitle

\section{Section 1}


\clearpage

\part{Schroedinger Picture}

%\maketitle2

\section{Section 1}

\end{document}
```

I need two parts titled say, `\part{Heisenberg Picture}` and `\part{Schroedinger Picture}`. These parts correspond to `Title 1`,`Supervisor X` and `Title 2`,`Supervisor Y` respectively. How can I redefine the `\maketitle` command to do this? (If it's too complicated, is there an easier method?)

Comment: Related (almost duplicate) question: [Using \maketitle twice in the same article](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6681). The same solution will work for your case.  I'll post an answer though because your question is slightly different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `titling` package does exactly what you require. I've also cleaned up your code to put the formatting parts into the `\pretitle` etc. commands leaving the contents of `\title` and `author` free of formatting.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\huge}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vspace{\baselineskip}}
\preauthor{\normalfont\normalsize\begin{center}\begin{tabular}[t]{c}}
\postauthor{\end{tabular}\end{center}\vspace{\baselineskip}}

\title{Title 1}
\author{Author\\Supervisors: Prof. X}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\part{Heisenberg Picture}

\maketitle

\section{Section 1}

\clearpage

\part{Schroedinger Picture}
\title{Title 2}
\author{Author\\Supervisors: Prof Y}
\maketitle

\section{Section 1}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}   
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%%%Solution package%%%
\usepackage{titling}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{\huge Title1 \\}
\author{\normalfont                 \normalsize
    Author\\                        \normalsize
    Supervisors: Prof. X}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\part{Heisenberg Picture}

\maketitle

\section{Section 1}

\clearpage

\part{Schroedinger Picture}

%still usable due to `titling`
\title{\huge Title2 \\}
\author{\normalfont                 \normalsize
    Author\\                        \normalsize
    Supervisors: Prof. Y}
\date{}

\maketitle%2

\section{Section 1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the same as my answer, but preserving the non-ideal practice of putting formatting into the title/author commands themselves.