# Two \maketitles in one page

Tags: page-breaking, titles, two-column

If I wanted to include two titles in one page, what can I do?
I've seen the [titling](http://ctan.org/pkg/titling) package as [this QA](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6681/using-maketitle-twice-in-the-same-article) suggested, but the titles came out in separate pages.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\begin{document}
\title{First title} 
\author{Author1, Author2} 
{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle}
\title{Second title}
\author{Author1, Author2}
{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle}
Some text
\end{document}
```

What I want is:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dual title in `twocolumn` mode causes the page breaks. Perhaps you'd just be interested in setting the title manually. Below I've taken the `\maketitle` constructions from the [`titling` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titling) [code](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titling/titling.dtx):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\begin{document}

\twocolumn[{
\begin{center}
  \LARGE First title
\end{center}
\vskip 2em
\begin{center}
  \large \lineskip .75em%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    Author1, Author2
  \end{tabular}\par
\end{center}
\begin{center}
  \large \today
\end{center}

\vspace{2\baselineskip}

\begin{center}
  \LARGE Second title
\end{center}
\vskip 2em
\begin{center}
  \large \lineskip .75em%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    Author1, Author2
  \end{tabular}\par
\end{center}
\begin{center}
  \large \today
\end{center}
}]

\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

You can now adjust the spacing and font to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the hooks provided by `titling` and set up some commands to define things conveniently. I use `\foreignauthor{}` and `\foreigntitle{}` which you use to defined the English versions. Then `\maketitle` will do what you want, I think.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
\preauthor{\begin{center}
\large \lineskip 0.5em%
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}}
\postauthor{\end{tabular}\par\end{center}}
\newcommand{\ftitle}{}
\newcommand{\foreigntitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\ftitle}{#1}}
\newcommand{\fauthor}{}
\newcommand{\foreignauthor}[1]{\renewcommand{\fauthor}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookc}{%
  {\begin{center}\LARGE \ftitle\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}%
  {\begin{center}\large \lineskip 0.5em%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
      \fauthor
    \end{tabular}\par\end{center}}}

\title{First title}
\author{Author1, Author2}
\foreigntitle{Second title}
\foreignauthor{Author1, Author2}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  Some text
\end{document}
```

[image: two titles, four authors]