# Making author names parallel and aligned in article document class

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

In the `article` document class, how to make author names parallel and aligned like we align inequalities and equations? Is there a default command to do so? I have tried `\and` but that just made author names in a line, not parallel.

If not, will you please tell me how to make it happen?

Comment: Is there a `documentclass` called `plain`? If I understand well `plain-tex` doesn't uses classes.

Comment: @Aradnix: Hey thanks for your interest. My gross typo, please see the edit.

Comment: Does `\author{Some Body \\ Another Body}` give the result you want? If not, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @PaulGessler: Thanks. I want to align the author names not only parallel but also aligned like we align inequalities and equations.

Comment: You really should add an MWE and a picture of your expected output. You want the two author names left-aligned, or right-aligned? And should the whole construct then be centered on the page, or aligned left/right? The question is not very clear as it stands, since author names don't have the same natural alignment points that equations/inequalities have.

Comment: The tag is wrong then, the question has nothing to do with plain tex. Review the answer of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199893/two-maketitles-in-one-page) maybe it can be useful for you. And please add a full MWE, you should know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a guess of what you might be after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{My title}
\author{\begin{tabular}{r@{\ }l}
  Extremely Long First Name & Last Name \\
                 First Name & Extremely Long Last Name
\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Comeseeconquer: The column specification `r@{\ }l` means there will be two columns - the first is `r`ight-aligned (or ragged left), while the second is `l`eft-aligned (or ragged right). Between the columns is a space `\ `. You might be interested in an `l@{\ }l` alignment... perhaps?

Comment: Thanks so much. Exactly, the latter is what I am after. And I have found it. :)